# ReactJS Radio Buttons

Tags: reactjs, radio-button

I am having trouble rendering information depending on the selected radio button. What should happen is when the yes button is clicked, 'Welcome user' should appear. When no is selected, 'Please login' should appear.

I am also having trouble with the states. When I click a button initially, the console button shows my state as blank. Then when I click no, the state updates as yes and vise versa. Not sure what is going on here.

```
render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
        <p>Did you go to the lecture?</p>

      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          value="No"
          checked={this.state.goToLectue === 'No'}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        No
      </label>
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          value= "Yes"
          checked={this.state.goToLectue === 'Yes'}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        Yes
      </label>

      <div> 
        <Response goToLecture = {this.state.goToLectue}/>        
      </div>
 );
}

  onFormSubmit = e => {        
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Chosen: ' + this.state.goToLectue);
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      goToLectue: e.target.value
    });
    console.log('value of goToLectue onchange: ' + this.state.goToLectue);
  }
```

function outside component

```
function Response(props) { 
  if (props.goToLectue) 
      return <h1>Welcome User</h1>; 
  else
      return <h1>Please Login</h1>; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a number of issues.

I have corrected them for you in a Codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YRWWEQ

1. In `Response` the `if` statement is being passed the `props.goToLecture` which can only be 'Yes' or 'No', both these string will resolve as truthy. I added `=== 'Yes'` to correct this. Tip for future is to stick to a `boolean` value wherever possible as it makes conditional statements a lot neater.
2. There seemed to be a mismatch of `lecture` and `lectue` in the code. I'm guessing the latter was a typo.
3. `<form>` tag was missing it's `</form>`
4. At the initial render the `goToLecture` is not set in the state and so it was throwing errors, this might be why you were seeing the blank screen. I added the default state as `undefined` to allow you the option of showing neither 'response' until a radio button is clicked if you choose.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Don't worry, we all are!

Answer (score 2):

I can see two problems in your code:

1) Response component expects a boolean in its `props.goToLectue` property, but you're passing it a string ('Yes' or 'No'). Either change `state.goToLectue` of the main component to also be boolean, or you can do something like `<Response goToLecture = {this.state.goToLectue === 'Yes'}/>`.

2) In your `handleChange` method you're logging `this.state.goToLectue` - this value is stale, you won't see the effect of the `setState` call immediately but only on the next `render()` call. You should be logging `e.target.value` instead.

Hope that helps.